# What you mean by separate call stack in thread?

Tags: multithreading, callstack

when we call thread.start(); it create separate call stack.what you mean by separate call  stack?

Comment: Did you mistag your question?

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack as a starting point.

Comment: Umm... by definition...